# Artifactory in docker- won't connect to postgres?

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to launch artifactory within a container, and it won't seem to connect to my postgres database.

I am launching it like so:

```
docker run  --network mynet --name artifactory -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/artifactory" -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE=postgresql -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_HOST=postgres -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PORT=5432 -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USER=artifactory -e JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password -p 9081:8081-i -t --rm  docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.10.2
```

The output it as such:

```
Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
Running as uid=1030(artifactory) gid=1030(artifactory)
Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-pro/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
Resolved JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE (postgresql) from environment variable
Resolved JF_SHARED_DATABASE_URL (jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/artifactory) from environment variable
Waiting for DB postgresql to be ready on postgres/5432 for 30 second
```

This shouldn't take 30 seconds, so this is an immediate red flag.
Then after the 30s expires, I see many of these:

```
2020-10-16T13:19:48.662Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [75be6b93f5c12126] [database_bearer.go:100        ] [main                ] - Connecting to (db config: {postgresql jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/artifactory}) [database]
2020-10-16T13:19:48.671Z [jfmd ] [WARN ] [75be6b93f5c12126] [jobs.go:92                    ] [main                ] -  [RETRY] Initiating database connection: pq: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet. Retrying in 1s ... (1/120) [database]
```

The startup output confirms it is set:

```
JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : da6d3e81a7c5
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PORT             : 5432
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USER             : artifactory
JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID                  : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/run/artifactory.pid
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE             : postgresql
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PASSWORD         : ******
JF_PRODUCT_DATA_INTERNAL            : /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
JF_PRODUCT_HOME                     : /opt/jfrog/artifactory
JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe,jfevt
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_HOST             : postgres
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_URL              : jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/artifactory
JF_SHARED_DATABASE_DRIVER           : org.postgresql.Driver
JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 172.19.0.3
JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : da6d3e81a7c5
JF_ARTIFACTORY_USER                 : artifactory
```

Not sure where else to take this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there,

you have a typo, it should be

`JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USERNAME`

and not

`JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USER`

Comment: Thank you for your eyes.  That nailed it!